# AWS Lambda Auto Scaling Desired Capacity instance termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, autoscaling

I'm trying to start some servers and scale up the number of instances in Auto Scaling Groups using AWS-Lambda.

```
import botocore.session

client = session.create_client('autoscaling')

   client.set_desired_capacity(
        AutoScalingGroupName='NAME',
        DesiredCapacity=1
    )
```

The server start normaly, the number of instances is properly changed:

[desired capacity changed to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJFE1.png)

The problem is, that after the start all instances in Auto Scaling Group are unexpected terminated and desired capacity goes back to 0.

[desired capacity changed to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UYJD.png)

Any suggestion why does it happen?

If I change desired capacity in EC2 Management Console, everything works properly.

Comment: It sounds like some other scaling rule defined on the Auto Scaling Group is setting the desired capacity back to 0.

Comment: or a cloudwatch alarm ?